# How do I join multiple (four) tables using sql with conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create an SQL query that conditionally pulls data from multiple tables.

I have four tables:

orders

```
+------+------------+------------+
| id   | date_added | currency   |
+------+------------+------------+
|   1  | 2018-07-23 |          1 |
+------+------------+------------+
```

order_items

```
+------+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| id   | order_id   | price      | product_id    | product_type  |
+------+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
|   1  | 1          | 100.00     |          1    |   ticket      |
+------+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

order_data

```
+------+--------------+---------------+
| id   | order_id     | ext_order_ref |
+------+--------------+---------------+
|   1  | 1            |         ABC   |
+------+--------------+---------------+
```

products

```
+------+------------+------------+
| id   | date       | product_id |
+------+------------+------------+
|   1  | 2020-03-12 |          1 |
+------+------------+------------+
|   2  | 2020-03-18 |          2 |
+------+------------+------------+
|   3  | 2020-03-20 |          3 |
+------+------------+------------+
```

I need to output orders with the following conditions:

- Each order in a row with total (calculated from order items with matching order id)
- The 'ext_order_ref' from the order_data table that matches that order
- Only include order items that have a specific product type
- Only include orders with products from a particular date range

Preferred output would look like this:

```
+------------+------------+--------------+
| order_id   | total      | ext_order_ref|
+------------+------------+--------------+
|   1        | 100        |          ABC |
+------------+------------+--------------+
```

My current query is basically like this; please advise

```
SELECT
orders.id as order_id,
SUM(order_items.price) as total,
order_data.ext_order_ref

FROM orders

INNER JOIN order_data
ON orders.id = order_data.ext_order_ref

RIGHT JOIN order_items
ON orders.id = order_items.order_id

LEFT JOIN products
ON order_items.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE order_items.product_type = 'ticket' AND products.date BETWEEN '2020-03-12' AND '2020-03-18'

GROUP BY orders.id
```

It almost works, but not quite. The date particularly is causing issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try putting parentheses around `products.date BETWEEN '2020-03-12' AND '2020-03-18'`

Comment: `ext_order_id` = 1? Or `ABC`

Comment: What issue is the date causing? There is no problem statement here!!

Comment: Updated it to be a _ref so that it is clear it's an externally provided string, not a primary key

Comment: Everything works until the inclusion of the date statement, upon which zero results are returned. I am new to SQL so even though this is working, I wanted to ask it here in case there was a better method I was not yet aware of; even with positive results: thus why I asked a question.

Comment: `order_data.ext_order_ref ` is a Alpha `ABC` but in `Preferred output` is becomes a numeric ONE

Answer (score 0):

First decide the driving table for the query and form the query based on the driving table.
Driving table is the one primary table from which other tables join.

[More information on driving tables from askTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:192812348072)

In your case, the driving table is Orders table. You are switching between `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. This will cause confusion in the resultset.

I have modified the query. See whether it works.

```
SELECT
orders.id as order_id,
SUM(order_items.price) as total,
order_data.ext_order_id

FROM orders

INNER JOIN order_data
ON orders.id = order_data.ext_order_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN order_items
ON orders.id = order_items.order_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN products
ON order_items.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE order_items.product_type = 'ticket' AND products.date BETWEEN '2020-03-12' AND '2020-03-18'

GROUP BY orders.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want outer joins at all.  If I follow the conditions correctly:

```
SELECT o.id as order_id,
       SUM(oi.price) as total,
       od.ext_order_id
FROM orders o INNER JOIN
     order_data od
     ON o.id = od.ext_order_id INNER JOIN
     order_items oi
     ON o.id = oi.order_id INNER JOIN
     products p
     ON oi.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE oi.product_type = 'ticket' AND
      p.date >= '2020-03-12' AND 
      p.date < '2020-03-19'
GROUP BY o.id, od.ext_order_id;
```

Note the use of table aliases so the query is easier to write and read.